# Как задать горизонтальную ориентацию и разрешение приложения Android?

Tags: android, эмулятор

Я с этим уже 2 дня бьюсь, ничего не выходит. В студио одно - в эмуляторах другое!

*Допустим, у меня есть экран 800x600 140 dpi (@1x), и у него бывает только горизонтальная ориентация.*

Я делаю макет, в студио всё выглядит идеально. Например, у меня экран 800dp, если я делаю отступы справа и слева по 250dp, в центре отображается контент в колонке шириной 320dp. 290+320+290 = 800.

Когда я запускаю приложение в стандартном эмуляторе или Genymotion, то центральная колонка становится намного тоньше - 20dp, то есть так, как если бы это был портретный режим! Я вообще не понимаю.

Что я уже пробовал, не помогло:

1. Создание альтернативных макетов для горизонта и ландшафта.
2. Создание альтернативных макетов с чётко заданной шириной.
3. `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDCAPE)` - это просто кладёт картинку на бок, при этом я вижу ту же узкую полосу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Горизонтальную ориентацию можно задать в manifest файле.

```
<activity
     android:name="LaunchActivity"      
     android:screenOrientation="landscape"...
```

Лучше не использовать конкретные величины при задании размеров элементов. Вы никогда не подгоните размеры под весь зоопарк устройств.

Правильно будет использовать вес `android:layout_weight`. 
Для этого назначить каждому элементу `android:layout_width = "0dp"` и `android:layout_weight="1"`,
где вес это процентное соотношение, которое должен занять контейнер, относительно родителя.

Comment: А со шрифтами тогда что делать?

Comment: И у меня всего один совершенно конкретный экран. Я вас уверяю - других не будет. Хотелось бы разобраться - если разрешение при @x1 800x600dp, почему он себя ведёт так, как будто стоит портретно. А главное - я совершенно не имею визуальной связи между макетом в IDE и в эмуляторах.

Comment: значение размера шрифта указываем в `sp`. а если не помещается использовать elipsize, либо библиотеки, которые автоматом подгоняют размер

Comment: дополнил свой ответ

Comment: Вот это - android:screenOrientation="landscape" - реально помогло! Спасибо!